# Product name is not showing up correctly on front-end

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product, name

I have created simple and configurable products named
Orange OYOBox Maxi,
Aqua OYOBox Maxi,
Niagara OYOBox Maxi,
Dusty Cedar OYOBox Maxi,
Yellow OYOBox Maxi
Here simple and configurable product has different SKU.
here is my front-end
[image]

but when I click on color, for example orange, Maxi word disappears
[image]

I have named correctly, still, I am getting this problem.
here is a screenshot of associate products of orange oyobox maxi(configurable product)

[image]

Comment: do you have mutistore site ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat yes

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Thanks man, every time you save me :))

Comment: then can you please check what is name of orange product in all store scope ? Might be there is one store where this product has name without "Maxi" word .

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat yeah. i got it, ill post the answer in sometime

Comment: okies, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multi-site setup then you need to check name of that orange product in all store scopes.

Most probably this product has different name in any store among all stores.

I hope it will help.